# Is there a functor $\mathit{Ch}(D^+(\mathcal{C})) \to D^+(\mathcal{C})$ of derived categories?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, derived-functors, derived-categories

Assume I have an abelian category $\mathcal C$ with enough projectives. Say the indecomposable projectives $P_i$ are indexed by $i\in I$ for some index set $I$.

Let $F\colon \mathcal C \to \mathcal C$ be a right exact functor of which I know the images $M_j = FP_j$ for all $j\in I$. Assume that I know projective resolutions $\cdots \to P_{i_{j,2}}\to P_{i_{j,1}} \to 0$ of all $M_j$. Now, for an object $N \in \mathcal C$ with projective resolution $\cdots\to P_{n_2} \to P_{n_1} \to 0$ of $N$, the image $\mathbf LFN$ under the left derived functor $\mathbf LF\colon \mathcal C \to D^+(\mathcal C)$ can be obtained by applying $F$ to the projective resolution $P_{n_\bullet}$ of $N$, which gives the complex $\cdots\to M_{n_2}\to M_{n_1}\to 0$ that should be quasi-isomorphic to $\mathbf LFN$. But since each $M_{n_k}$ is quasi-isomorphic to $P_{i_{n_k,\bullet}}$, shouldn't it be possible to determine $\mathbf LFN$ only from the resolutions $P_{i_{n_k,\bullet}}$ of the $M_{n_k}$?
Of course, the structure

$$\begin{matrix}&& \vdots && \vdots\\&& \downarrow && \downarrow\\\cdots & \rightarrow & P_{i_{n_2,2}} & \rightarrow & P_{i_{n_2,1}}\\&& \downarrow && \downarrow\\\cdots & \rightarrow &  P_{i_{n_2,1}} & \rightarrow & P_{i_{n_1,1}}\end{matrix} \tag{$\dagger$}$$

is no double complex; the columns are exact since they are resolutions of the $M_{n_k}$'s, but horizontally, the structure is only exact up to chain homotopy.

I would have thought that ($\dagger$) thus is an element in $\mathit{Ch}(D^+(\mathcal C))$, basically because horizontally, it has the complex property up to homotopy. Does it represent an element in $D^+(\mathcal C)$, or, if you wish, is there a functor $\mathit{Ch}(D^+(\mathcal C)) \to D^+(\mathcal C)$, such that the diagram

$$\begin{matrix}\mathit{Ch}(\mathit{Ch}(\mathcal C)) & \overset{\mathrm{can}_*}{\to} & \mathit{Ch}(D^+(\mathcal C)) \\
\llap{\mathrm{tot}} \downarrow && \downarrow\\
\mathit{Ch}(\mathcal C) & \underset{\mathrm{can}}{\to} & D^+(\mathcal C)\end{matrix}$$
commutes?

*Remark.* Of course, if I only knew the resolutions $P_{i_{n_k, \bullet}}$ of the $M_{n_k}$'s, I could recover latter from the former and build the reresentative $M_{n_\bullet}$ of $\mathbf LFN$ out of them. But what do I do if I have another functor $F'\colon \mathcal{C} \to \mathit{Ch}(\mathcal C)$ or $F'\colon \mathcal{C} \to D^+(\mathcal C)$ instead, for which the images need not be quasi-isomorphic to complexes concentrated in one degree?

Comment: How do you define a quasi-isomorphism in $Ch(D^+(\mathcal{C}))$ ? Since you don't have kernel and images in $D^+(\mathcal{C})$, the notion of $D^+(D^+(\mathcal{C}))$ is not clear to me...

Comment: @Roland Indeed, you are right, I didn't properly think about this. But the question is only partially ill-posed, I think, so I try to correct it.

Comment: Ok, I'll think about it or maybe someone can provide an answer. Just a guess, I would say no there is no interesting functor $Ch(D^+(\mathcal{C}))$ doing what you want. In fact if $A,B\in D^+$, then $...\to 0\to A\to B\to 0\to...$ is a complex in $Ch(D^+(\mathcal{C})$ and what you want seems to functorially makes its totalisation, but this is the same thing as a functorial cone which does not exists. On the other hand, I believe there is a totalisation functor $D^+(Ch(\mathcal{C}))\to D^+(\mathcal{C})$, which you can simply define using universal properties.